# How to combine into a single event even though the logs don't come right after each other

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to combine the logs into a single event much like multiline even though the logs are not right next to each other.

As in I want to combine logs with the same tag instead of combining them to "previous" or "next" as multiline does.

How do I do that?

Comment: How will you know when to combine/flush events?  `multiline` has a `stream_identity` that could possibly be used if you turned on `enable_flush`.  The basic problem you'll have is knowing when the events are complete so that they can be pushed out of the filter.

Comment: Hmmm. So you are saying that because we don't know when the events are complete, there is no way to combine logs that are not right after each other?

Comment: Pretty much -- that `enable_flush` on the `multiline` plugin is marked as not ready for production -- but what it would do is periodically flush out events that never got their "next" event. If you know when you are done, it's definitely possible to write a custom plugin to gather on some key and flush when you reach the end.